# Complex second order differential equations with vector variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I have 3 second order differential equations that need to be solved. I obtained them by separating the velocity vector into x, y and z components so that i can solve them separately.
[The parent equation and 3 equations can be seen in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hPrt.png)

- x is displacement
- v is velocity vector
- omega is spin
- w is wind vector
- derivative is taken w.r.t time

I have the following questions

Since each equation has all x, y and z components of velocity how can they be solved? They are not constant through time so should this be converted into a partial differential equation

What about |v-w| its scalar but changes with time?

How can this equation be solved for position x?

Comment: There is no field function involved, so nothing "partial". Just write it as a first order system, $\dot r=v$, $\dot v=a(r,v)$. Then apply further manual transformations or feed it into a numerical solver.